# Complex Number Upper Estimation

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Hello I am trying to understand the following solution but cannot

Let $a_{n}$ be a bounded sequence of complex numbers. Show that for each $\varepsilon>0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} n^{-z}$ converges uniformly for $\operatorname{Re} z \geq 1+\varepsilon$. Here we choose the principal branch of $n^{-z}$.

Solution
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} n^{-z},\left|a_{n}\right| \leqslant C, \operatorname{Re} z \geqslant 1+\varepsilon .$ Apply Weierstrass M-test, $\left|a_{n} n^{-z}\right| \leqslant$ $C n^{-\operatorname{Re} z} \leqslant \frac{C}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}=M_{n}, \sum M_{n}<\infty \Rightarrow \sum a_{n} n^{-z}$ converges uniformly for $\operatorname{Re} z \geqslant 1+\varepsilon$.

Specifically on the line where it says  $\left|a_{n} n^{-z}\right| \leqslant$ $C n^{-\operatorname{Re} z}$. I understand that $|a_n|$ is bounded by $C$ but why is $|n^{-z}| = n^{-\Re(z)} $? Which properties of complex number does this come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write $z=a+ib$ with $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$. Then
$$|n^{-z}|=|n^{-a-ib}|=|n^{-a}||e^{-ib\ln n}|=n^{-a}$$
since $|e^{-ib\ln n}|=1$.